# GKE internal ingress keep attaching and detaching the Network Endpoints in zone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking

I have been observing `Network Endpoint Group` attach and detach events in GKE internal ingress logs.

> kind: "Event"
> message: "Attach 2 network endpoint(s) (NEG "k8s1-28f1xxx2-xxxxx-app-1443-e95eee64" in zone "us-east1-b")"***

> kind: "Event"
> message: "Detach 6 network endpoint(s) (NEG "k8s1-28fxxx2-xxxxxx-app-1443-e95eee64" in zone "us-east1-b")"***

One thing to note, We have been observing the high latency in our test when this events occur. Can someone explain why GKE keeps attaching and detaching the Network endpoints and does it impact network performance ?
Is there any way to avoid it and always keep ingress in "Scheduled for sync" state.

Comment: Are you using cluster autoscaler and/or HPA?

Comment: Hi Gari, No, we are not using hpa and also have disabled the cluster autoscaler.

Comment: Which GKE version are you using?

Comment: Hi Gari, version is 1.22.8-gke.201. Does autoscaling/hpa use causes this ?

Comment: I believe that there was a bug in 1.22 which causes this.  I’ll double check and let you know.  But moving to a later GKE 1.22 version should resolve this.

Comment: Thanks @GariSingh, we will also check the feasibility of upgrading the version.

Comment: @saurabh umathe Has your issue been resolved by moving to a later GKE 1.22 version?